# Error in passing value of local variable in other function

Tags: c, variables, local

I am making a program in C in which I am trying to use the values of local variable in other function. Lets say I have two function `foo1` `foo2`.

```
int foo1()
{
  int a=2,b=3,c;
   c=a+b;
   return c;
 }

int foo2(int c)
{
 printf("Value of C is %d",c);
}
```

is this method correct, if not what else is the way to use values of local variable in other function?

Comment: how `foo1()` and `foo2()` is related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this -

```
int foo1()
{
  int a=2,b=3,c;
   c=a+b;
   return c;
 }


// c will be passed to the function and printed
int foo2(c)
{
 printf("Value of C is %d",c);
}
// get the result of foo1()
int val = foo1();
// call foo2() with the result of foo1()
foo2(val);
```

Comment: int val = foo1();  foo2(val), where I should write these two lines?

Comment: inside the main() or where you are calling using those functions.

Answer (score 2):

first of all, this two functions foo1()  and foo2()  are  not related...
and local variables have block scope only.
If you want to use them in other functions  make them global or use pass by value  and pass by reference methods to pass the variables from one function to others...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, and you should not use local variables from other functions directly.

But in your case you are lucky: the value from `foo1()` you are interested in is returned to the caller.

This way you can use it as you like:

```
...
int value = foo1();
foo2(value);
...
```

or even shorter:

```
...
foo2(foo1());
...
```

Comment: where i should include those two lines, in which function

Comment: @arjunsaini Wherever you want to call them, maybne in the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make c variable global so that every function can use it.
other way is to call this returning function in foo2() so that the returned value can be printed.
one way:

```
int foo1(){ 
int a=2,int b=3;
int c=a+b;
return c;
}

int foo2(){ 
printf("value of c = %d",foo1());   //returned value of function foo1() used
}
```

other way is :

```
int c=0;  //defined global

void foo1()
{ 
int a=2,int b=3;
c=a+b;
}

void foo2()
{ 
printf("value of c = %d",c);
}
```